# How to initialize random state when using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to initialize my React app with a randomized state, but while developing [I realized that React.StrictMode will try to render your component twice](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074) in order to find bugs. This causes the initial print to console to be different from what's actually printed on the screen.

Am I using `useState` correctly or is React telling me to do something else?

Code:
`App.js`

```
export function Game(props) {
  const [theSecret, _] = useState(
    Array(4)
      .fill()
      .map(() => getRandomInt(4))
  );
  console.log(theSecret)
  return <button>{theSecret}</button>
}
```

`index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Game />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: So is your actual question *How to make sure what's printed on the page matches what prints in the console in strict mode?* I mean what's ultimate goal?

Comment: @codemonkey Both. I want them to match but also I feel that the different results generated by StrictMode mean I am doing something wrong but I don't understand what.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use useState lazy initialization

```
export function Game(props) {
  const [theSecret, _] = useState(() =>
    Array(4)
      .fill()
      .map(() => getRandomInt(4))
  );
  console.log(theSecret)
  return <button>{theSecret}</button>
}
```

It will prevent the random value from generating in every render